# Android App Stops and Crashes when using a long nested loop

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, nested

I am trying to make a nested loop that will show me on screen the combinations of letters and numbers, I created a nested loop that will make a string of 15 characters then it will be put in a string named "pass". "tr" is a activity that i made to translate the numbers resulted in letters or numbers (something like ASCII table), I initially thought that the translate activity was the problem so i commented the whole thing out leaving just the loops and the app freeze. Here is the code:

```
  private void nestedLoopTest() {
            for (int aa = a; aa < 35; aa++) {
                for (int bb = b; bb < 35; bb++) {
                    for (int cc = c; cc < 35; cc++) {
                        for (int dd = d; dd < 35; dd++) {
                            for (int ee = e; ee < 35; ee++) {
                                for (int ff = f; ff < 35; ff++) {
                                    for (int gg = g; gg < 35; gg++) {
                                        for (int hh = h; hh < 35; hh++) {
                                            for (int ii = i; ii < 35; ii++) {
                                                for (int jj = j; jj < 35; jj++) {
                                                    for (int kk = k; kk < 35; kk++) {
                                                        for (int ll = l; ll < 35; ll++) {
                                                            for (int mm = m; mm < 35; mm++) {
                                                                for (int nn = n; nn < 35; nn++) {
                                                                    for (int oo = o; oo < 35; oo++) {
                                                                        pass = tr
                                                                                .Translate(aa)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(bb)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(cc)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(dd)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(ee)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(ff)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(gg)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(hh)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(ii)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(jj)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(kk)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(ll)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(mm)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(nn)
                                                                                + tr.Translate(oo);
                                                                        passtxt.setText(pass);
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I solve this ?
**EDIT:**
The app freezes about 10mins and after that it display the last generated string, How can i make the code show every string and pause ?

Comment: Aaaaarrrrrggggghhhh.  My eyes!

Comment: Two loops will do.  The outer one 0 to 14, the inner one 0 + outer index to 34 + outer index.  I'm too tired to work out the code, but there's your hint.  I'm sure someone will turn this comment into a solution, or other more awake Droiders will offer better solutions.

Comment: Can you be more explicit please, because i don't see how I can get a 15 characters long strings from 2 loop.

Comment: Loop-Oriented programming :D , this can be serious. Can you specify what you need with more details?

Comment: I need to make all possible combinations of 15 characters(letters & numbers) and then pun them in a string to show them on screen.

Comment: You realize that if you have 15 characters, and can choose all 26 standard letters + 10 numbers as possibilities that that means you'll have 36^15 possible combinations, right?

Comment: Please very carefully explain what you are trying to do. Use a few examples. Without that, there's not much we can do...

Comment: 36^15 = 221,073,919,720,733,357,899,776, So this algorithm fails now I know that but how can I make something similar but not freeze the phone ?

Comment: If you want to check if some string matches a certain pattern (e.g. contains just A-Z & 0-9) use a regular expression. You can't calculate all possible strings (it would take [7005559 years](https://www.google.de/#q=221073919720733357899776+ns+to+years) if you could generate 1 per nanosecond).

Comment: Ok thanks my mistake I did not thought of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that what you have is O(35^m) where m = # of for loops you have. Not even desktop computer can handle that many operations.  Don't understand what you're trying to do, but you should come up with better algorithm.

Comment: So how can I make something similar for mobile ?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I am trying to try all possible combination on a string to see what combination matches.

Comment: You may find using a regex is more valuable and workable than what you are attempting to do above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on the last loop, you are writing:

```
for (int oo = o; oo < 35; oo++)
```

I see 4 problems here:

1. infinite (oo) is too big to fit into an integer
2. infinite (oo) is not equal to 0
3. infinite (oo) is grater than 35
4. it is pointless to increment infinite (oo) it will still be infinite